# How to install Proof General for Emacs on Mac?

Tags: emacs, coq, theorem-proving

I am new to Emacs and perhaps that is the problem but I was following the instructions here:

https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG

in particular after I added the given lines to my `.emacs` file, I did (`M` is the alt/option key):

```
M-x package-refresh-contents RET
```

but I got the error message:

`[no match]`

what is going wrong?

---

maybe this what I am doing wrong, what does:

```
 M-x package-refresh-contents RET followed by M-x package-install RET proof-general RET
```

mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me (TM):

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)

;; Bootstrap use-package
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (package-install 'use-package))

(use-package proof-general
  :no-require t
  :ensure t)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line will work if you have melpa as your package source. See the answer of ejgallego:

```
 (require 'package)
 (setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
      (add-to-list 'package-archives
          '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

 (package-initialize)
```

If you add these lines to your .emacs - file and then

```
 M-x package-refresh-contents (followed by return)
 M-x package-install (followed by return and then `proof-general`)
```

then it will work without explicitly adding the package in your .emacs-file.